# Scala Dataframe/SQL: Dynamic Column Selection for Reporting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Context**:

We have a model which has 5 flows.

- Flow-1 : Input Data from different sources , these are input to Flow-2
- Flow-2, Flow-3 and Flow-4 : are ML models each dumping few fields to s3
- Flow-5 : Reporting Layer with data from output of Flow-2,Flow-3,Flow-4
- Overall data size is very small

**Problem**:

- Flow-5 which is reporting layer based on few SQL with input data coming from Flow-2,Flow-3 and Flow-4.
- Flow-2,Flow-3 and Flow-4 has one common joining field and remaining fields are different.
- We can create a SQL joining Flow-2,3,4 data stored in three different tables with few calculations/Aggregation.However the number of output fields from Flow-2,3,4 may vary in each run.

  - Problem-1: every time s3 file (Flow-2/3/4) structure changes, which often results in issue during COPY, as the target table schema differs from s3 file structire (to fix, need to manually add/delete fields in target table,to align with s3 data)
  - Problem-2: for any additions/deletion in s3 files, need to make changes in reports by adding/removing column

**Approach**:

- SQL way - standardize s3 dump/target table/report SQL i.e. standardize the number of possible columns in each flow(2,3,4) output,also in the target table, so that if any fields are not available, just load them as NULL/blank during s3 dump and COPY as blank. Standardize target table structure aligned with s3 template. Also standardize reporting SQL
- SCALA/SPARK : Currently exploring this option. to perform a PoC, created two s3 dumps,created two dataframes in scala, tried dataframe joins as well as spark SQL join. Im still not sure if there is anyway we can dynamically pick new columns ie making the spark code generic.

  - with creating dataframes directly pointing to s3, we can solve the COPY data (dynamic fields) to target table problem.
  - however, the reporting SQL issue still persists (or atleast I dont know, need to find a way how can it be handled)

**Question**:

Is there anyway,can we handle the issue (dynamic column selection in SQL) in Scala/SparkSQL ?
Note: s3 file always contains only the required fields from each run.Issue is not reading the dynamic fields from s3 (which will be auto taken care by dataframe, instead issue is how can we make the SQL(saprkSQL/API) code to handle this)

**Example/Scenario-1**:

- **Run-1**

  - df1= country,1st_buy      (here dataframe directly points to s3, which has only required attributes)
  - df2= country,percent      (here dataframe directly points to s3, which has only required attributes)

```
--Sample SQL code (need to convert to sparkSQL/dataframe API)
SELECT df1.1st_buy,
       df1.percent/df2.percent -- DERIVED FIELD
FROM df1,df2
WHERE df1.country=df2.country
```

- **Run-2** (here one additional column was added to df1)

  - df1= country,1st_buy,2nd_buy  (here dataframe directly points to s3, which has only required attributes)
  - df2= country,percent     (here dataframe directly points to s3, which has only required attributes)

```
****how can we handle this part of new field 2nd_buy dynamically****

--Sample SQL code (need to convert to sparkSQL/dataframe API)
SELECT df1.1st_buy,
       df1.2nd_buy,
       df1.1st_buy/df2.percent -- DERIVED FIELD
       df1.2nd_buy/df2.percent -- DERIVED FIELD
FROM df1,df2
WHERE df1.country=df2.country
```

**Example/Scenario-2**:

- **Run-1**

  - df1= country,1st_buy      (here dataframe directly points to s3, which has only required attributes)

```
--Sample SQL
SELECT country,sum(df1.1st_buy)
FROM df1
GROUP BY country

--Dataframe API/SparkSQL
df1.groupBy("country").sum("1st_buy").show()
```

- **Run-2** (here one additional column was added to df1)

  - df1= country,1st_buy,2nd_buy  (here dataframe directly points to s3, which has only required attributes)

```
****how can we handle this part of new field 2nd_buy dynamically****

--Sample SQL
SELECT country,sum(df1.1st_buy),sum(2nd_buy)
FROM df1
GROUP BY country

--Dataframe API/SparkSQL
df1.groupBy("country").sum("1st_buy","2nd_buy").show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  1.
  val sqlScript = "select col1, col2, .... from ... "
  // string we can create dynamic
  val df = spark.sql(sqlScript)
 2. try use schema =  = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("id",LongType,true),
  ....
  )) 
  // and then use schema.fieldsName... or
  val cols: List[Columns] = ...
  // in df.select(cols:_*)
 3. get schema (list fields with json file)
     package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType}

import scala.io.Source

object DFFieldsWithJson extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class TestData (
    id:         Int,
    firstName:  String,
    lastName:   String,
    descr:      String
  )

  val dataTestDF = Seq(
    TestData(1, "First Name 1", "Last Name 1", "Description 1"),
    TestData(2, "First Name 2", "Last Name 2", "Description 2"),
    TestData(3, "First Name 3", "Last Name 3", "Description 3")
  ).toDF()

  dataTestDF.show(false)
//  +---+------------+-----------+-------------+
//  |id |firstName   |lastName   |descr        |
//  +---+------------+-----------+-------------+
//  |1  |First Name 1|Last Name 1|Description 1|
//  |2  |First Name 2|Last Name 2|Description 2|
//  |3  |First Name 3|Last Name 3|Description 3|
//  +---+------------+-----------+-------------+

  val schemaJson =
    """{ "type" : "struct",
      |"fields" : [
      |{
      |    "name" : "id",
      |    "type" : "integer",
      |    "nullable" : true,
      |    "metadata" : { }
      |  },
      |  {
      |    "name" : "firstName",
      |    "type" : "string",
      |    "nullable" : true,
      |    "metadata" : {}
      |  },
      |  {
      |    "name" : "lastName",
      |    "type" : "string",
      |    "nullable" : true,
      |    "metadata" : {}
      |  }
      |  ]}""".stripMargin

  val schemaSource = schemaJson.mkString
  val schemaFromJson =   DataType.fromJson(schemaSource).asInstanceOf[StructType]

  println(schemaFromJson)
//  StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(firstName,StringType,true), StructField(lastName,StringType,true))


  val cols: List[String] = schemaFromJson.fieldNames.toList
  val col: List[Column] = cols.map(dataTestDF(_))
  val df = dataTestDF.select(col: _*)


  df.printSchema()

//  root
//  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)

  df.show(false)
//  +---+------------+-----------+
//  |id |firstName   |lastName   |
//  +---+------------+-----------+
//  |1  |First Name 1|Last Name 1|
//  |2  |First Name 2|Last Name 2|
//  |3  |First Name 3|Last Name 3|
//  +---+------------+-----------+
}



}
```

Comment: @ mvasyliv thank you so much for the details,much appreciate.

Comment: @ mvasyliv thank you so much for the details, much appreciate. I tried the point-3 above and you are suggesting to have a json file with required fields specific to a dataframe, which can pick required data. The issue is not wrt reading the required fields as s3 file is usually loaded with only required fields from each run. The issue is how we can handle this in sparkSQL/dataframeAPI whenever there is an addition/deletion of fields in s3(dataframe). I was not very clear in the original post, hence I have updated the post above with question and few oversimplified scenarios.

Comment: let question.
do you use format parquet to S3 file?

Comment: if you use parquet file in S3.
1. you can read parquet files in folder 
val df = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("S3/user/vmv/data/")
mergeSchema = true, let receive schema to all files.
2. when you save to parquet file you can set parameter "spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata" to true. need seach like parametr when save to S3. and you have actual schema to all files and spark read this schema .
if your file  not have field "col2000" after merge schema file have column "col2000" with value null.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html - see Schema Merging

Comment: @ mvasyliv. Thanks again for the details. I took some time last few days  contemplating the options you mentioned, also referred few docs as Im fairly new to spark,as I mostly from SQL background.Much appreciate your help in providing the direction, so that I was able to look in detail the concepts.
Regarding the solution to the above problem, the option is open i.e. we can consider any data format or approach. For now in the short term Im planning to implement using Approach (SQL way) mentioned above, But it is not an efficient way, instead I should handle via scala/spark/pyspark.

Comment: As far the s3 format, we could use parquet. Specifically in this case parquet mergeSchema does not help,as Im not facing the issue in reading the required fields from s3 to dataframe (s3 always contains only required fields and even if s3 contains additional fields, we can use a json file with only required fields which we can filter form s3 as you explained above) . The issue (which Im still not clear) is how do I dynamically generate the SQL based on the fields in s3? 
  val sqlScript = "select col1, col2, .... from ... "
  // string we can create dynamic
  val df = spark.sql(sqlScript)

Comment: would it be possible if you can share a reference code snippet to generate dynamic sql?

Comment: can you give examples and i will try to solve your problem on them.

Answer (score 1):

{ Examples:

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, column, sum}

object DynamicColumnSelection extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  case class c1(
     country: String,
     st_buy: Double,
     nd_buy: Double
  )

  case class c2(
     country: String,
     percent: Double
  )

val df1 = Seq(
  c1("UA", 2, 4),
  c1("PL", 3, 6),
  c1("GB", 4, 8)
  )
  .toDF()

  df1.show(false)
//  +-------+------+------+
//  |country|st_buy|nd_buy|
//  +-------+------+------+
//  |UA     |2.0   |4.0   |
//  |PL     |3.0   |6.0   |
//  |GB     |4.0   |8.0   |
//  +-------+------+------+

  val df2 = Seq(
    c2("UA", 2.21),
    c2("PL", 3.26)
  )
    .toDF()
  df2.show(false)
//  +-------+-------+
//  |country|percent|
//  +-------+-------+
//  |UA     |2.21   |
//  |PL     |3.26   |
//  +-------+-------+


  // Inner Join
  val df = df1.join(df2, df1.col("country") === df2.col("country"), "inner")
      .select(
        df1.col("country"),
        df1.col("st_buy"),
        df1.col("nd_buy"),
        df2.col("percent")
      )
  df.show(false)
//  +-------+------+------+-------+
//  |country|st_buy|nd_buy|percent|
//  +-------+------+------+-------+
//  |UA     |2.0   |4.0   |2.21   |
//  |PL     |3.0   |6.0   |3.26   |
//  +-------+------+------+-------+


  val res1DF = df.withColumn("st_buy_percent", 'st_buy/'percent)
    .withColumn("nd_buy_percent", 'nd_buy/'percent)

  res1DF.show(false)
//  +-------+------+------+-------+------------------+------------------+
//  |country|st_buy|nd_buy|percent|st_buy_percent    |nd_buy_percent    |
//  +-------+------+------+-------+------------------+------------------+
//  |UA     |2.0   |4.0   |2.21   |0.9049773755656109|1.8099547511312217|
//  |PL     |3.0   |6.0   |3.26   |0.9202453987730062|1.8404907975460123|
//  +-------+------+------+-------+------------------+------------------+


  // GroupBy + sum
  val data = Seq(
    c1("UA", 2, 4),
    c1("PL", 3, 6),
    c1("UA", 5, 10),
    c1("PL", 6, 12),
    c1("GB", 4, 8)
  )
    .toDF()

  val resGroupByDF = data
    .groupBy("country")
    .agg(sum("st_buy").alias("sum_st_buy")
    ,sum("nd_buy").alias("sum_nd_buy"))

  resGroupByDF.show(false)
//  +-------+----------+----------+
//  |country|sum_st_buy|sum_nd_buy|
//  +-------+----------+----------+
//  |UA     |7.0       |14.0      |
//  |PL     |9.0       |18.0      |
//  |GB     |4.0       |8.0       |
//  +-------+----------+----------+


  val resGroupByDF1 = data.groupBy($"country").sum()
  resGroupByDF1.show(false)
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+
//  |country|sum(st_buy)|sum(nd_buy)|
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+
//  |UA     |7.0        |14.0       |
//  |PL     |9.0        |18.0       |
//  |GB     |4.0        |8.0        |
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+


  val exprs = data.columns.map(sum(_))
  val resGroupByDF2 = data.groupBy($"country").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
  resGroupByDF2.show(false)
//  +-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
//  |country|sum(country)|sum(st_buy)|sum(nd_buy)|
//  +-------+------------+-----------+-----------+
//  |UA     |null        |7.0        |14.0       |
//  |PL     |null        |9.0        |18.0       |
//  |GB     |null        |4.0        |8.0        |
//  +-------+------------+-----------+-----------+

  val exprs3 = List("st_buy", "nd_buy").map(sum(_))
  val resGroupByDF3 = data.groupBy($"country").agg(exprs3.head, exprs3.tail: _*)
  resGroupByDF3.show(false)
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+
//  |country|sum(st_buy)|sum(nd_buy)|
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+
//  |UA     |7.0        |14.0       |
//  |PL     |9.0        |18.0       |
//  |GB     |4.0        |8.0        |
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+


  val exprs4 = data.columns.toList.filter(_ != "country").map(sum(_))
  val resGroupByDF4 = data.groupBy($"country").agg(exprs4.head, exprs4.tail: _*)
  resGroupByDF4.show(false)

//  +-------+-----------+-----------+
//  |country|sum(st_buy)|sum(nd_buy)|
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+
//  |UA     |7.0        |14.0       |
//  |PL     |9.0        |18.0       |
//  |GB     |4.0        |8.0        |
//  +-------+-----------+-----------+

  // Select
  val cols = data.columns.toSeq
  val selectDF1 = data.select(cols.head, cols.tail:_*)
  selectDF1.show(false)
//  +-------+------+------+
//  |country|st_buy|nd_buy|
//  +-------+------+------+
//  |UA     |2.0   |4.0   |
//  |PL     |3.0   |6.0   |
//  |UA     |5.0   |10.0  |
//  |PL     |6.0   |12.0  |
//  |GB     |4.0   |8.0   |
//  +-------+------+------+
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot @mvasyliv for providing the examples.Appreciate. I will try to perform some tests based on the above examples and keep the thread posted.Between ,why does .agg function above needs head and tail, as "exprs3" is already a column type ie. Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column], where as head/tail is required only for string types. Just adding "exprs3: _*"  in .agg is resulting in error.